# Why does eventListeners only execute if radio is physical checked?

Tags: javascript, radio-button, click, onkeydown

### Problem

I'm not understanding why the `input` `addEventListener` `change` only execute when I physically check the `radio input`. 
The `event` should fire every time the `radio` button is checked.
But it refuses to acknowledge if `javascript` `checkes` it (whether by `click` or `onkeydown`) 
How would I get `javascript` to fire `addEventListener` `change` regardless of how it was checked?

### Demo

To console log:

- Press 1 or 2 `(javascript does not acknowledge radio being checked)`
- Click the sentence `(javascript does not acknowledge radio being checked)`
- Click the radio button

```js
let input1 = document.getElementById("input1")
let input2 = document.getElementById("input2")
let div = document.getElementById("div")



//Listens for keypress and checkes one of the radios
document.onkeydown = function (e) {
 if (e.key==="1") {input1.checked = true;}
  if (e.key==="2") {input2.checked = true;}
}



//Listens for sentence click and checkes one of the radios
div.addEventListener ("click", function () {
  if (input1.checked){input2.checked = true;}
  else {input1.checked = true;}
})



//When ever inputs are checked
input1.addEventListener ("change", function () {
 console.log("Radio1 was checked")
})
input2.addEventListener ("change", function () {
 console.log("Radio2 was checked")
})
```

```css
#div {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
Click radio, click this sentence or (Press 1 or 2) to log
</div>
<input type="radio" name="a" id="input1"/>
<input type="radio" name="a" id="input2"/>
```

Comment: changing property programmatically doesn't trigger user events. You need to create and dispatch event yourself for that

Comment: See this for a direct coded example: https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/dispatchEvent.html